# What's the correct way to append a variable to a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little Angular JS page.  There's a search form.  When I click the button, I perform the search by loading JSON data from a URL.

My question is, what's the correct way to modify the URL string to include the value in the form?

My failed attempt is included, you can see I'm doing a `+searchCriteria+` which obviously wrong ...

Any help is appreciated!

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

    Search Field: <input type="text" ng-model="searchCriteria">
    <button ng-click="myFunction()">Search</button>

[ ... ]

</div>

[ ... ]

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8984/solr/carlistings1/select?indent=on&q=make:' + searchCriteria + '&wt=json';
        alert("url="+url);
        $http.get(url)
            .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.response.docs;});
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: did you got `searchCriteria` in alert ?

Comment: Alert never displays, I'm assuming the `var url =` crashes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference `$scope`:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8984/solr/carlistings1/select?indent=on&q=make:' + $scope.searchCriteria + '&wt=json';
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!  Been pulling my hair out for hours.  (New at this.)

Comment: @HardikVaghani Thanks ... is that just this: `+encodeURIComponent($scope.searchCriteria)+` ?

Answer (score 0):

use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8984/solr/carlistings1/select?indent=on&q=make:' + encodeURIComponent(searchCriteria) + '&wt=json';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The encodeURLComponent tip is very helpful, but I was also missing the `$scope.`

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8984/solr/carlistings1/select?indent=on&q=make:' + $scope.searchCriteria + '&wt=json';
```